# Media queries doesn't work with 415px

Tags: html, css, media-queries

**html**

```
<h1 class="map__item">Find us</h1>
```

**css(1400px screen)**

```
.mail__item {
    position: absolute;
    top: 340px;
    right: 71px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}
```

**css(415px screen)**

```
@media only screen and (max-width: 415px) {
    .map__item {
        top: 33px;
        font-size: 4em;
    }  
}
```

***browser ignore code for 415***

Comment: Is the media query for 415px below the rest, or above? Can you provide the whole css file, so we can look closer?

Comment: it's in a middle, but I try to /*comment */ another queries - the same effects

Comment: Place it at the bottom of the css file, unless you have media queries which are targeting even smaller screens.

Comment: Would you mind showing the whole file? I think there is a syntax problem.

Comment: http://hello-site.ru/share/YiOPx7SNSyQEMHq/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/122660/discussion-between-asimovwasright-and-olga-k).

Comment: 1/ **map** or **mail**? Is it a typo only here or also in your page? 2/ Does it work at 414px and 320px or does it fail at 415px _and below_?

Answer (score 1):

**Update Css**

```
 @media screen and (max-width: 415px) {

    .map__item {
        top: 33px;
        font-size: 4em;
    } 
    }
```

**Live Demo** [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/patelsumit5192/2dgs88pt/)

> **Notes:** Change height and width in fiddle then result are display

Comment: but there is change on 800 px